# Using localStorage to store current logged in user data in React JS

Tags: reactjs, authentication, local-storage

I'm working on a MERN project which requires user authentication. Is it a good idea (professional and safe) to use localStorage to store current logged in user's data? If not what else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Save the Barear Token into the local storage. But never passwords.